# Multiple where clauses on multiple tables Laravel without join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently developping a crud application with Laravel. I have an Ad class that contains a user_id and a model_id. I want to filter my ads with user and model table fields. I managed to do the request with multiple joins, but I wonder if there is a way without joins and without the DB class. I tried to write a request with with() function but it doesn't work.

Code of the working request with joins

```
$ads = DB::table('ads')
        ->join('bike_models', 'ads.model_id', '=', 'bike_models.id')
        ->join('users', 'ads.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('images', 'ads.id', '=', 'images.ad_id')
        ->select('ads.*', 'bike_models.*', 'users.*', 'images.*')
        ->where($filters)
        ->get();
```

Working request without where clause

```
$ads = Ad::with(['model', 'user', 'images'])->get();
```

Not working request with where clause

```
$ads = Ad::with(['model','user','images'])->where($filters)->get();
```

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT**

Here is the content of the filter array

[image: Filter array]

Here is the content of my database :

Ads table : id, price, km, model_id, user_id

bike_models table : id, year

Comment: Could you add the value of $filters as well? (I think you are using columns that the Ad model doesn't have)

Comment: Please simpify the question: remove un-related fields. Have you tried using Eloquent relationship models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with()` is for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). You can't use normal `where` functions to filter based on eager loaded relations because these relations are queried after the main query in finished.

To get what you want:

1. You need to split your `$filters` array by relation: 1 filter array for `model`, other for `user`, and other for `images` **if your `$filters` array can have filters for all relations**. If you want to filter based only on `model` relation, you can skipp this step.
2. You have 3 options to use your array to filter:

### [WhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```php
$ads = Ad::with(['model','user','images'])
    ->whereHas('model', function($q) use ($filters) {
        $q->where($filters);
    })
    ->get();
```

> Look that if you want to filter by many relations with many `$filters` array you need to adjust this query, because `whereHas` works only for one relation at time.

### [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```php
$ads = Ad::with(['user','images', 'model' => function($q) use ($filters) {
        $q->where($filters);
    }])
    ->get();
```

> In the same way, if you want to filter by many relations with many `$filters` array you need to adjust this query, because you need to create a functionto filter every loaded model in `with`.

### [Constraining Eager Loads With Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence)

```php
$ads = Ad::with(['user', 'images'])
    ->withWhereHas('model', function($q) use ($filters) {
        $q->where($filters);
    })
    ->get();
```

To get a more accurate solution, please add your Laravel version to the question. This answer was based on `Laravel 9.x`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split your filters array into 2 separate arrays: `filters` for filtering Ads and `modelFilters` for filtering relation (bike_models).

Then you can try to use `with` and `whereHas` or [`withWhereHas`](https://arjunphp.com/laravel-eloquent-withwherehas/) functions:

```php
$modelFilters = [['year', '>=', '2018'], ['year', '<=', '2022']];
$filters = [...]; // other filters: km, price

Ad::query()
  ->with(['user', 'images'])
  ->withWhereHas('model', fn ($query) => $query->where($modelFilters))
  ->where($filters)
  ->get();
```

or you can do:

```php
$modelFilters = [['year', '>=', '2018'], ['year', '<=', '2022']];
$filters = [...]; // other filters: km, price

$filterModels = fn ($query) => $query->where($modelFilters)

Ad::query()
  ->with([
    'user', 
    'images', 
    'model' => $filterModels
  ])
  ->whereHas('model', $filterModels)
  ->where($filters)
  ->get();
```

The result will be the same